# What XML Transformation is suitable here

Tags: xml, transformation, configurable

I am trying to narrow down on a suitable XML Transformation language/utility which would allow me to do some pretty heavy XML transformation ( file sizes i expect to be around 100 kb) . The source and target files consist of nearly 280 unique elements with up to 3 levels of object nesting representing a customer technical order. I have two to three streams of XML docs which i need to transform into a single XML document ( eg: 2 XML docs, one from an Order Management and one from a Resource Management system to be processed to generate a single target doc).

The transformations involve evaluation of nodes in the source streams and either assigning them to the target schema nodes or doing some transformation such as setting variable values for the target schema. The number of nodes in the source and target schema are not necessarily equal. I would like ideally the rules to be configurable rather than embedded in code (not sure if this is feasible) at the same time processing-light.

I have mix of  evaluative and conditional elements defined as Business rules  ( using a mix of scripting and XPath it would crudely look like this "`If(/OrderData/Servicetype != /ResourceData/ServiceType) then /Target/ServiceType = /OrderData/ServiceType)`"

I am still evaluating if a single pass parser will suffice the entire transformation. My main aim is to:

1. Have a configurable file which can define parsing rules
2. An engine which can read this file and parse as per the rule. Mostly to be configurable i believe it would need to be more of an interpreter based one since i believe the configurability requirement will automatically push compilation out the window.
3. Configurable file could be definable in some defined syntax for evaluations, functions etc.

Any addition to the XML schema will obviously need an addition to the ruleset.
Ideally I just want to have to update the ruleset and the inputXML Schemas to have the Engine adapt to new parsing rules/input.

I want to be able to manipulate the entire schema in one pass.
Trying to parse the entire Target schema resulted in Java class size error being thrown which means I need to split the schema to parse it.
Further due to this XSLT I presume will only result in large processing times owing to the size. This I presume only leaves me an option of XML String parsing. (I wish there was `awk` for XML :) ).
I would be glad if someone can guide me to any resource which can help. Is there an equivalent JAVA utility ?

I know this sounds like a Christmas Wishlist written to Santa :) but in case someone has already done something like the above please give me a shout or a suggestion. I can share the XML schemas and a sample of the exact translation rules being defined if required.

Comment: Have you considered a decent XSLT2 processor, such as Saxon?  I'm sure it can handle what you need.  BTW,  what is a _"Java class size error "_?  Also, without examples of input, output and an explanation of why XSLT isn't appropriate, this question borders on being off-topic for SO.

Comment: HI Jim, Thanks for the suggestion. I am discussing this with my technical team, I had my mind on Saxon but before I took it up I just thought about testing the waters for anything new which might be floating around.                                    I am using an MDM tool to store my data. On of the utilities in this tool transforms the XSD structure into equivalent Java class structures. What the tool ended up doing was  taking the entire XSD and creating such a large class by default that it exceeded the 64k limit set by Java.

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands upon thousands of people using XSLT to do exactly what you describe. Look no further. It can even be reasonably described as "awk for XML". You'll get a lot of productivity benefits by using XSLT 2.0 instead of version 1.0, which is still more widely available than 2.0. For file sizes of a few hundred Kb you don't need to worry about streaming.